# Perl Script stops at ' sign when checking text from the input

Tags: regex, perl

I do not know Perl and I have a script that should be removing special characters from input.

Script looks like this:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;
use Encode qw(encode decode);
my $str = $ARGV[0];
$str = decode('utf8',shift);
$str =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n@.\\,\",\/,\\,<,>,{,},(,),;,:,=,?,¦,%,#,\&,+,*,',!,\$,^,\-,_,–,ä,ü,ö,ß,é,à,è,ù,â,ê,î,ô,û,ç,ë,ï]/ /gi;
print $str;
```

Sample text that goes as Input:

> **'**04/07/2022 15:16:10   UPCIT\user1 :  INFO: The related Ticket INC00112233 has changed it's Status from In Progress  to Pending**'**

you will notice that input text line is quoted by ' ' (single quotes signs)
in console look like this

```
perl /pathtothescript/scriptname.pl 'text to process with the script'
```

Sample of output:

> there will be no output only Program exited with error code 130, because I have terminated script as it was stacked.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what could be causing for the script to stop when it gets to the ' sign in the text?

this is sample of few test I have been performing on my local machine.
Also to point out that tests were done on Ubuntu and script will run on Redhat, I am not 100% sure that this has anything with this...

[image]

Comment: During script execution, I attempted to enter ' and Enter, and there it goes, script continued executing and I received desired output. Now, since I have no knowledge I'll have to research more on this how to have script continue executing when it comes to ' sign.

Comment: This seems more likely a shell quoting issue than a Perl issue

Comment: You are correct, but I am trying to find a way how this can be made to work...

Comment: Why do you have to many commas inside the character class braces `[...,<,>,{,},(,),...]` Inside character class braces you do not need commas between characters. Also, your whole character class is negated by `^`, so it will actually, for example, match all characters that are not `<`, `>`, `{` etc. I sense some confusion there, since you also have alphanumerics there `a-zA-Z0-9`. Maybe you think it only applies to them? That's wrong, if so.

Comment: You might also see if maybe you can use some of the predefined character classes, such as `\W` (non-alphanumeric).

Comment: Word of advice, don't post pictures of text. Use copy paste, especially with code or input, so people can copy paste and try themselves. If you force people to try your input or code by typing it in themselves, chances are they are not going to bother.

Comment: Also, it seems very unlikely that the code you posted transforms the input as in the picture. That would mean it changes `[` to `{`, and the only replacement you make is to `  ` space. You should never post output that was not produced with the code you say you were using.

Comment: Apologies for picture, not an intention to forbid copy/pasting.

Comment: Apologies for the picture, not an intention to forbid copy/pasting. I will repost with editable content

A character class is regex expression, it filters nonalphanumeric characters and all listed characters in the class. 
Problem remains with shell that have issue interpreting arguments with odd number of quotation signs. 
Example when script fail to interpret argument:
perl script.pl 'This is string's text'         # because it stops at exit sing and never ends to the end of the string.

Comment: "_suggestion on what could be causing for the script to stop when it gets to the ' sign in the text_  -- because by the example in the question it appears that input is delimited by that very character, a single quote, so altogether there is `prog.pl  'input...'more...'`.  So the `'` inside input string terminates input.  Use double quotes, `prog,pl "input"`.  Or, safer and cleaner, put input in a file and read it in the program. This is a matter of how that program is to be used.  But the program seems faulty to start with (does it even work?), please see my answer.

Comment: If the character is in fact a backtick -- ` -- then it's much worse since that starts a shell command.  then you definitely want all input to be in a file (well, unless input is passed to the program inside another program by yet other commands in which case this may be a completely different situation)

Comment: Could you change `it's` to `its` in whatever generates the status message?  That wouldn't fix the code, but it would both avoid the issue and be grammatically correct. :)

Comment: If you type `perl /pathtothescript/scriptname.pl 'text to process with the script'` at a shell prompt, your script will not see the single quotes. It will see a single argument, the string `"text to process with the script"` (to be clear that string starts and ends with `'t'`). Using double quotes rather than single quotes in the shell command will do exactly the same thing in this case. If you want the input string to include a single quote character, you can't simply surround it with single quotes, but that's a shell issue, not a Perl issue.

Comment: `perl pathtothescript/scriptname.pl "string containing 'single' quotes"` is one way to pass a string that contains single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are a few basic things to straighten out in what the question honestly tries (and very nearly gets right), and to suggest perhaps more structured ways to do it.

The lists of characters to keep have been supplied in a comment.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use utf8;                              # for what's in this source
use Encode qw(decode);                 # for what need be manually decoded
use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );  # takes care of standard streams

my $str = decode('UTF-8', shift, Encode::FB_CROAK);

# Characters to keep
my $ch_non_ascii = q(ä ü ö ß é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï);
my $punct_symb = 
    q(@ , . " \/ \ < > { } ( ) # ; : = ? ¦ | % & + * ' ! $ ^ - –);

# Note: typed with spaces for readability but then spaces will be kept.  
# Can keep it like that but now remove spaces from these variables and
# then they will be removed from input as well, if that is desired
#s/\s+//g for $ch_non_ascii, $punct_symb;

my $re_del = qr/[^\w $punct_symb $ch_non_ascii]+/xx;  # \w --> [a-zA-Z0-9_]

# Or consider using POSIX classes, at least [:punct:]. See text

$str =~ s/$re_del//g;

say $str;
```

The [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qr/STRING/msixpodualn)
operator generates a proper regex pattern.  The `q()` is an [operator form](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) of single quotes. With [`/xx` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#/x-and-/xx) all spaces inside a character class are ignored, useful for readability (available from Perl v5.26).

Now running (note double quotes)

```
script.pl "a,B.!'{)] /\@^~ ö ß ≠"
```

prints

```
a,B.!'{) /@^ ö ß
```

The `~`, `]`, `\`, and `≠` have been removed as they aren't listed to be kept. If you use `[:punct:]`, instead of listing punctuation/symbols by hand, then only `≠` is removed since the POSIX class includes the others (omitted from the list by an oversight?).  The list of included characters is in the [perlrecharclass, footnote 5](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#%5B5%5D).

Another way, likely far cleaner and safer, is to use POSIX character classes, in particular for punctuation and/or Unicode properties that Perl adds for them.  See [POSIX character classes in perlrecharclass](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#POSIX-Character-Classes)
and [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops) (with [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode) and [perluniintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro)).

If that's good enough for your needs then this becomes trivial

```
$str =~ s/[^ [:alnum:] $ch_non_ascii [:punct:] ]+//gxx;
# or
$str =~ s/[^ \p{PosixAlnum} $ch_non_ascii \p{XPosixPunct} ]+//gxx;
# or, including full-range unicode
$str =~ s/[^ \p{XPosixAlnum} \p{XPosixPunct} ]+//gxx;
```

The POSIX classes and their corresponding Unicode properties may differ here or there, please see docs and experiment.  I space out elements in character classes merely for readability.

These are normal character classes, with `[:punct:]` and `\p{...}` in them, so add to them if there are more characters to remove which aren't in the predefined POSIX/Unicode sets.

See linked docs for details.

Comments on some details in the question

- The question asks about a `'` character in input. That's about how to enter input -- so about your shell, files, pipelines or whatnot. How to read input depends on how it is supplied. If it's directly from the command-line it should generally be double-quoted.

  If you need to pass to the program very particular things which could confuse the shell, one way to do it is to put them in a file and read the file instead.
- Character class just lists characters (no comma between them!), so that in a regex any one of those is matched by it. If it starts with `^`, like `[^...]`, then any character that is *not* listed in it is matched -- that is a "negated" character class.  Start [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Using-character-classes).
- A `$str` is read from `@ARGV` -- and then it is `shift`-ed from it, too.  No need for both.
- Note that writing `utf8` or `UTF-8` may differ; see on this [in Encode](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8)

Comment: I will need to do the reading first, as I said I'm not familiar with perl and still need to learn a lot. I'll get back as soon I make some progress on your answer. Thank you for this ...

Comment: regex is a negation of listed character class, you are right, anything that is not in that character class listed should be removed. The character class presented in the script is actually an allowed list of chars that could be found in the string and should stay in.

Comment: @djdulee Alright, hang in with me for a minute to review this (it's been a while :) ...

Comment: wrote: The question specifically asks about a ' character in input. That's about how to enter input -- so about your shell, files, pipelines or whatnot. What is not stated in the question, except for a basic example: 
this is a part of BMC Remedy developer where I am calling the script with input param to process "not allowed characters" and return the result into the variable. The program has an action block, where I choose Execute script and there I give instructions on how to do it: to_text_plain.pl '$Summary_Filed$\ -this is a variable where the string is saved.

Comment: @djdulee OK, there's two things here. (1) Input -- that's another matter, how to read input from the shell under your circumstances.  (2) the program -- you say "_The character class presented in the script is actually an allowed list of chars_" -- now I don't understand. That character class lists all kinds of special characters, like `}`,`=`,`?`,`¦`,`%`,`#`,`&`,`+`,`*`  (I picked a few) -- those kinds of things you want removed, right? But `a-zA-Z0-9` you want kept, right (these in regex can go as `\w` -- a "word character", which also includes `_`) ...? Is this correct?

Comment: @djdulee That "character class" in the question isn't right how it's written so it confuses -- can you provide a straight-up list of things you want removed?  And/or those to keep?  Btw, the last part of that list in your regex are accented characters ... you want those out? Then that makes it a very different question, since Unicode is choke full of all kinds of those things.  Do you then really mean to keep only ASCII ...?

Comment: @djdulee  Perhaps this will be useful:  (1) in a regex, `[abc.]` means "match either of `a`, `b`, `c`, `.` (literal period).  So any of those listed inside.  No commas to separate them, no escaping them (except a few special ones, like `]`).  You may use patterns, so `[\w.,]` would mean match any one "word character" or `.` or `,`.  (A "word character", `\w`, is any one of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).  (2) But, `[^...]` means match anything _other_ than those listed.  (3) We can't mix them -- either use `[...]` OR `[^...]`.   I think ... you meant to mix them, right?  That would explain it.

Comment: @djdulee OK, now I'll wait for you to clarify these things -- or met me know if what I write isn't clear!  Also let me know what I can/should add to the answer...

Comment: As I do not know what could be a "not allowed character" I have made this regex to match any character that I know it can be allowed by typing s/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n@.\\,\",\/,\\,<,>,{,},(,),;,:,=,?,¦,%,#,\&,+,*,',!,\$,^,\-,_,–,ä,ü,ö,ß,é,à,è,ù,â,ê,î,ô,û,ç,ë,ï]/ /gi; because next step is Remedy processor and if it comes to anything not in this regex it will stop running.

Comment: @djdulee OK, thank you -- can you show those without regex context?  Just a list of characters to allow, and a list to not allow.  (Because when you use `^` in the regex and then escape them etc I don't know  what you mean.  So just a straight-up list, like a-zA-Z0-9 \n @ " / \ < > ... etc.  (that a-z is clear enough :)

Comment: @djdulee As for those accented ones (ä,ü,ö,ß,é,à etc) -- what do you mean wit those? Exclude them?  Then that brings the whole Unicode into play ... do you then want to only keep ASCII?

Comment: I do appreciate your help with this, thank you.
**the list of allowed chars is like this**: any letter lowercase or upper case, any number 0-9 @ , . " /  \ < > { } ( ) ; : = ? ¦ | % # & + * ' ! $ ^ - _ – ä ü ö ß é à è ù â ê î ô û ç ë ï
By adding ^ in front I am actually looking for anything that is not in this list so that script can replace those chars not in the list.

Comment: @djdulee OK, so I got it exactly backwards!  I thought these were things to remove, the punctuation and brackets and special characters and all.  But this is the list of things to keep, and so remove everything else.  I'll edit now...

Comment: @djdulee Alright, edited, please review and let me know.

Comment: @djdulee Fixed a typo in text, a few other small improvements

Comment: @djdulee Corrected an omission in a description (of what characters get removed from my example run -- it's a few more than I originally discussed here)

Comment: Hello, this is very explanatory I have a lot of readings. I have tested with changes and it is working, but I have to use single quotes ' for wrapping  because when i am using using double quotes the script stops. Let me first read everything you left for me and I'll get back if I have questions. This is excellent for me at this stage. 
I will experiment with not using negation ^ and entering only characters I would like to remove, but this only during the time when I learn list of characters that should be removed. Which type of character is this in Perl: ` ~ < >

Comment: @djdulee OK, let me know if questions come up.  (1) It's likely clearer to add characters of interest (to be kept/removed in this case) to a list, and then in regex say what to do with them  (2) What do you mean by "_which type of character_" ?  All of: backtick, `~`, `<`, `>,`are ASCII.  In a regex, neither is `\w`, a "word character."  The [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) escapes them all, as "_ASCII non-"word"_" characters.   That last one, `–`, appears to be `&mdash;`, not ascii but `U+2014` (that's hex, so `\x{2014}`) Does this answer "_which type_" they are?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I am testing this right now and it is working perfect for now. If I do not see any new issues, then we can close this topic since you provided more then perfect answer. I still need to learn Perl but this is good for start. Thanks

Comment: I have found first one that I need removed it'c backtick
**perl to_plain_text.pl "[200~'04/07/2022 15:16:10 UPCIT\user1 : INFO: The related Ticket INC00112233 has changed it's Status from In Progress to` Pending"
> ** 
it's waiting for input when I do attempt like this.

Comment: @djdulee Ah, OK, now I get it -- the backticks in the shell run a command! We can use them inside of a command to run another command and use the output (I form log-file names that way sometimes, by running `date` with suitable options inside a pair of backticks and use that on the command line with other things for filename).  This is a little tricky, to stop the shell from interpreting backtick that way.   For that ... I'd suggest again the following: put those strings in a _file_ instead, and then your Perl program can read that file for its input. Then no character there will be a problem.

Comment: You are right regards to how is the best to process the text. This is going to be a challenge but either way, your solution works perfect and now I understand this code a little bit more then i did in time I made a question. Thank you very much for guide and for your help. I'll probably modify this code a little bit along I learn something new or if any new character comes along that should not be in the text. Thanks again.